# How to struct.unpack array of values in a c3d file using Python

Tags: python

I'm coding my own script to retrieve values from a c3d motion capture data file. Data are stored as integer in an array of dimension 1x14. How can I retrieve these values ?

Thank you for any help,

Arnaud

Comment: What kind of integers are they? 32-bit? 16-bit? Big-endian or little-endian? Signed or unsigned? Once you know, it should be quite easy to build the format string required by `struct.unpack`.

Comment: It should be 16-bit integers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the c3d file format at all, but if you know what kind of integers your data contains, it's easy to unpack them. You just need to give `struct.pack` an appropriate [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings).

For 16 bit integers, the format code you'll want is `h` or `H` (depending on whether the numbers are signed or unsigned). You also may need to start the string with a specifier of the byte ordering (`<` or `>` for little-endian and big-endian, respectively) if the integers are not stored with the same byte ordering that your CPU uses natively.

Try something like this:

```
parsed_ints = struct.unpack("<14h", raw_data) # 14 little-endian signed 16-bit ints
```